# document versioning and concurrent updates in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create a collection which supposed to hold versioned data (only a message for the sake of simplicity).

For each message there is a `link` which provides access to that message:

```
{
  link: 'A57awpO3e',
  message: 'foo',
  version: 1
}

/message/A57awpO3e -> foo
```

Lets say we create two more message based on the previous message:

```
{
  link: 'A57awpO3e',
  message: 'bar',
  version: 2
},
{
  link: 'A57awpO3e',
  message: 'baz',
  version: 3
}
```

Asking for the 3rd version of this message should return:

```
/message/A57awpO3e/3 -> baz
```

#### Requirements

I want to create a solution which:

1. works with concurrent requests trying to create multiple versions of the same document. Meaning that I want a unique `version` per link.
2. satisfies [MongoDB Data Model Design best practices](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/)

#### Possible solution

To be sure that `version` numbers are unique per `link` this must be an atomic update which reads the max version and creates the new document and modifies the version.
The best I've come up with was to restructure the collection to look like this:

```
{
  link: 'A57awpO3e',
  maxVersion: 3,
  messages: [
    {
      message: 'foo',
      version: 1
    },
    {
      message: 'bar',
      version: 2
    },
    {
      message: 'baz',
      version: 3
    }
  ]
}
```

So I could do something like this:

```
data.findAndModify({
  query: { 'link': 'A57awpO3e' },
  update: {
    $inc: { maxVersion: 1 }
    $push: {
      'messages': {
        message: 'foo bar',
        version: maxVersion
      }
    }
  },
  new: true
});
```

The problem is that I don't know how to access the maxVersion at this point and this solution would create a "growing" document in MongoDB terms, so it should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo do not support identity seeds (like oracle or mssql),
to simplify this problem - maybe messages could be stored inside of array?

```
message: [
   {msg:"my message", dateTime:2016-04-29 11:22:45.9950},
   {msg:"your message", dateTime:2016-04-29 11:22:46.0110} 
]
```

$push -ing an item will always add it to the end of array, and then you can get version by array index of message?

**To get last message  use $slice: -1**

To avoid grooving data structure - if you need to have all version - data need to grow. If you could keep last n - then make a job which will remove first entries (something like capped collection - but in this case capped array)

> EDIT

[please find discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110639/discussion-between-akoskm-and-profesor79)

There is an edge-case if the field you're sorting by isn't always unique and then it's not guaranteed (at least can't clarify that) that the returned order will always be the same.

Comment: So what you're saying is to leave out the `version` field completely and return the n-th element of the array on `/message/A57awpO3e/{n}`?

Comment: @akoskm - yes - as adding version could be extremely tricky and expensive in concurrent app

Comment: I see, this is an interesting solution, how would you modify this to meet my 2. requirement: avoiding the growing datastructure?

Comment: I could insert those messages as separate entries into the collection with timestamp - like you did - and on `/message/A57awpO3e/{n}` I could sort them by created date and return the n-th element from the array.

Comment: @akoskm that's other solution but keep in mind that in extreme case you could have 2 entries :-)

Comment: In which case? Theoretically if n entries have the same timestamp I would end up with n entries, is that what you mean?

Comment: So avoiding the version field altogether may lead to the same timestamp across multiple entries - which would completely ruin the purpose of versioning, and as an alternative I can go against MongoDB Data Model Design best practices. As a third alternative I could implement a an [auto-incrementing sequence field](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#procedures), which would be expensive I agree, but it would work.

Comment: @akoskm but you will still have array position **INDEX** which will make the work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110639/discussion-between-akoskm-and-profesor79).